# Matlab upper and lower triangular matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix-calculus

I created an upper triangular matrix in U and a lower triangular matrix L from A matrix but when I go to make the inverse procedure in order to take my original matrix the matlab returns the right elements in right row and column but the rows are in wrong place. What I do wrong?

```
A=[1 -2 3;9 2 1;4 -3 2]
[L,U,P]=lu(A)
B=P*A
C=L*U
```

A =

```
 1    -2     3
 9     2     1
 4    -3     2
```

L =

```
1.0000         0         0
0.4444    1.0000         0
0.1111    0.5714    1.0000
```

U =

```
9.0000    2.0000    1.0000
     0   -3.8889    1.5556
     0         0    2.0000
```

P =

```
 0     1     0
 0     0     1
 1     0     0
```

B =

```
 9     2     1
 4    -3     2
 1    -2     3
```

C =

```
 9     2     1
 4    -3     2
 1    -2     3
```

Comment: Isn't it C=P*L*U?

Comment: with this C=P*L*U it returns:
C =
     |4    -3     2|
     1    -2     3|
     9     2     1|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MatLab does a strange trick, namely:
$$
A=P^{-1}LU,
$$
so just pose:
$$
B=P^{-1}LU,
$$
and verify that $A=B$.

Answer (score 0):

From MATLAB's documentation

> `[L,U,P] = lu(A)` returns an upper triangular matrix in `U`, a lower triangular matrix `L` with a unit diagonal, and a permutation matrix `P`, such that `L*U = P*A`. The statement `lu(A,'matrix')` returns identical output values.

MATLAB gives you, in essence, the $L$ and $U$ that return you a *permutation* of $A$. But since this permutation is easily invertible, you can either consider

$$PA = LU$$
or
$$A = P^{-1}LU.$$

However, $P$ is orthogonal, so $P^{-1} = P^T$, so you can confirm the following result in MATLAB code:

```
A=[1 -2 3;9 2 1;4 -3 2];
[L,U,P]=lu(A);
A-P'*L*U % This should have entries very very small.
```